# Netbeans 7.1 Build Hell

Tags: netbeans

Each time I try to build *any* netbeans project (Ubuntu 11.10), I get the following build failure:

```
   annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
   (use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
```

Not sure what I did to cause this to happen, as I was building fine moments before. Now, I can't build anything.

I only have JDK 6 installed -- where is the source switch being set and how can I unset it?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project, and select project properties; the first item on the left is should be Sources -- make sure its selected. Look towards the bottom on the right side at Source/Binary Format. It should be set to JDK 6. If not, change it.

Next, go to libraries (right below Sources on the left). The top entry on the right side, Java Platform, should be set to something like "JDK 1.6 (Default)" If its not, then try to change it in the combo box, if there are no other options, choose manage platforms to configure Netbeans to use the correct JDK.

Comment: My netbeans IDE was set to SUN JDK 1.6 in all of the appropriate places. The issue, I think, was that my system didn't have a JAVA_HOME path set (it was a fresh system) and I was using sun JDK instead of openJDK. When I was building with the built in maven on Netbeans, it detected my JDK and everything was fine. When I switched to my local maven repo, I got all the build errors.

Comment: Oh, so you're using Maven then?

Comment: Yeah, Maven 3.0.4. I am sorry for not specifying.